# Why or-combined != sometimes does not behave as expected

Tags: python-3.x, comparator

So I was trying to create a tic tac toe game and I ran into a problem with one of my method where I could not figure out why it was going on an infinite loop. My code is:

```
def player_input():
    marker = ''
    while marker != 'X' or marker != 'O':
        marker = input('Do you want to be X or O: ').upper()
        print(marker)

    if marker == 'X':
        return ['X','O']
    return ['O','X']
```

What it is currently doing is that it keeps asking the question even when the user inputs X or O. The code works when I use the condition:

```
while not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O'):
```

Comment: Try putting parentheses in that line: `while (marker != 'X') or (marker != 'O'):`

Comment: In your first while loop conditions, when marker = 'X' then it also doesn't equal 'O'. Conversely, when it is 'O' then it also doesn't equal 'X'.

Comment: @EricJin `or` is a low-priority operation. It's a good reflex to check whether things behave differently with parenthesis but here it is equivalent.

Comment: This is actually not a python question. It is clearly more about logics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your logic in checking `marker != 'X' or marker != 'O'`.

Let's pretend `marker == 'X'`. So our expression evaluates to `False or True` which evaluates to True. Same goes with `marker == 'O'`. Our expression here evaluates to `True or False` which evaluates to True.

You should be using `and`, not `or`.

Your second expression, `not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O')` is equivalent to `(not marker == 'X') and (not marker == 'O')`, so it works. ([De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws))

```py
def player_input():
    marker = ''
    while marker != 'X' and marker != 'O': # change from 'or' to 'and'
        marker = input('Do you want to be X or O: ').upper()
        print(marker)

    if marker == 'X':
        return ['X','O']
    return ['O','X']
```

Comment: Maybe it's a matter of preferences but I find `while marker not in ("X", "O"):` easier to read, especially when you start using way more than 2 options.

Comment: Yeah. Usually I use `a in ('choice 1', 'choice 2')` over `a == 'choice 1' or a == 'choice 2'`

Comment: Additionally using `not in` and `in` opposed to `a == '1' or a == '2'` is slightly faster as well

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies within `while marker != 'X' or marker != 'O'`.

What is happening in your first attempt is that even if `marker != 'X'` is *False* (marker *is* equal to 'X'), then `marker != 'O'` MUST be True. So it'll be always asking for input again, because it is "one or the other".

Suppose `marker != 'X'` is an expression *A* and `marker != 'O'` is an expression *B*. Then, according to [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) you have:

`(not (A and B)) is equivalent to ((not A) or (not B))`

And:

`(not (A or B)) is equivalent to ((not A) and (not B))`

Therefore, your last attempt works as expected because:

`while not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O'):`

Is equivalent to:

`while (not marker == 'X') and (not marker == 'O'):`